# Pivot table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my current table:

[image: This is my curent table:]

I am trying to pivot it to obtain this structure:

| Segment | API | Mobile | Web |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Enterprise | 1,739,410.3 | 3,459,504.5 | 4,661,960.09 |
| SMB | 410,281.84 | 939,104.25 | 1,247,303.96 |
| Startup | 2,621,454.13 | 5,702,420.6 | 7,898,458.36 |

But this is what I get when I use this query:

```
CASE WHEN channel = 'API' THEN sum(cost) END AS api,
CASE WHEN channel = 'Mobile' THEN sum(cost) END AS mobile,
CASE WHEN channel = 'Web' THEN sum(cost) END AS web
```

| Segment | API | Mobile | Web |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Enterprise | 1,739,410.3 | null | null |
| Enterprise | null | 3,459,504.5 | null |
| Enterprise | null | null | 4,661,960.09 |
| Enterprise | null | null | null |
| SMB | 410,281.84 | null | null |
| SMB | null | 939,104.25 | null |
| SMB | null | null | 1,247,303.96 |
| SMB | null | null | null |
| Startup | 2,621,454.13 | null | null |
| Startup | null | 5,702,420.6 | null |
| Startup | null | null | 7,898,458.36 |
| Startup | null | null | null |

How can I return only one row for each [Segment]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modify your code like this:

```
SELECT segment,
  SUM(CASE WHEN channel = 'API' THEN cost END) AS api,
  SUM(CASE WHEN channel = 'Mobile' THEN cost END) AS mobile,
  SUM(CASE WHEN channel = 'Web' THEN cost END) AS web
FROM test
GROUP BY segment;
```

By this way, your get the cost of each segment by case-when block first,  then group by only 'segment' column, so that you can get one row for each segment.
In your query provived, I guess you need to GROUP BY segment, channel, so you get one [segment, channel] combination in each row.

Comment: To see the output more clearly, you can add [channel] to your SELECT